# It's possible use the Visual Recognition API physically?

Tags: ibm-watson, visual-recognition

I'd like to know if it's possible use the Visual Recognition API physically, as an industrial conveyor that differentiates objects to select them or as in a robot for example.

Comment: As long as you can train with "good" and "not good" images, yes. It's just an API, though - of course you will have to do the interfacing of images into VR, and handling the response to take whatever action you want.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Most likely I will have to use Arduino or PLC because it's a school project. With that in mind what would you suggest, use the Watson API or use OpenCV and which camera at a good price would you recommend? I saw a project with Kinect on Youtube, but I don't know if it would work well.

Answer (score 0):

Your camera needs to have a resolution to allow a trained Visual Recognition instance to be able to differentiate between different objects in different physical orientations.  The Visual Recognition instance needs to be trained with both "good" and "not good" images.  If you are looking at objects on a conveyor, you need to train with "good" images of the object in question in a variety of different orientations (on it's side, on it's back, etc.), and a variety of "not good" images (again in different orientations).  Once you have your instance trained, then you simply call the API and pass in the image that you want to "look" at, and it will return what it "thinks" the object is, based on the training that you did.

Comment: Thank you, that helped me. Would you have a camera at a good price to recommend me?

Comment: I don't have a recommendation.  I would just focus on resolution, and recovery speed if using the camera for an industrial conveyor example.  In other words, if you grab a frame from the camera now, how long do you need to wait before you can grab the next frame?  How quickly can the camera transmit the image to your application so you can then send it to Watson for classification?  That speed will be important.